# create an executable war for Spring MVC and jetty embedded project with maven

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am trying to make an executable war for a spring MVC project with embedded jetty. I want to run the war with the command java -jar myProject.war an start the main class. I just want to use the maven-war-plugin but it does not work

this is the class MAin

```js
public class Main
{
 public static void main(String... anArgs) throws Exception
    {
        new Main().start();
    }

 private WebServer server;
    
    public Main()
    {
        server = new WebServer(8024);        
    }
    
    public void start() throws Exception
    {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

and this is the WebServerClass

```js
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.RequestLog;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPool;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

/**
 * Example WebServer class which sets up an embedded Jetty 
 * appropriately whether running in an IDE or in "production" 
 * mode in a shaded jar.
 */
public class WebServer
{
 static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WebServer.class.getName());
    // TODO: You should configure this appropriately for 
    // your environment
    private static final String LOG_PATH = 
      "D:/workspace/Butuc/logs/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log";

    private static final String WEB_XML = 
      "META-INF/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml";
    private static final String CLASS_ONLY_AVAILABLE_IN_IDE = 
      "com.sjl.IDE";
    private static final String PROJECT_RELATIVE_PATH_TO_WEBAPP = 
      "src/main/java/META-INF/butuc";

    public static interface WebContext
    {
        public File getWarPath();
        public String getContextPath();
    }

    private Server server;
    private int port;
    private String bindInterface;

    public WebServer(int aPort)
    {
        this(aPort, null);
    }

    public WebServer(int aPort, String aBindInterface)
    {        
        port = aPort;
        bindInterface = aBindInterface;
    }

    public void start() throws Exception
    {
        server = new Server(createThreadPool());

        server.addConnector(createConnector());
        server.setHandler(createHandlers());        
        server.setStopAtShutdown(true);

        server.start();       
    }

    public void join() throws InterruptedException
    {
        server.join();
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception
    {        
        server.stop();
    }

    private ThreadPool createThreadPool()
    {
        // TODO: You should configure these appropriately
        // for your environment - this is an example only
        QueuedThreadPool _threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
        _threadPool.setMinThreads(10);
        _threadPool.setMaxThreads(100);
        return _threadPool;
    }

    private ServerConnector createConnector()
    {
     HttpConnectionFactory httpConnectionFactory = new HttpConnectionFactory();
     ServerConnector _connector = new ServerConnector(server, httpConnectionFactory);
        _connector.setPort(port);
        _connector.setHost(bindInterface);
        return _connector;
    }

    private HandlerCollection createHandlers()
    {                
        WebAppContext _ctx = new WebAppContext();
        _ctx.setContextPath("/");

        if(isRunningInShadedJar())
        {          
            _ctx.setWar(getShadedWarUrl());
        }
        else
        {            
            _ctx.setWar(PROJECT_RELATIVE_PATH_TO_WEBAPP);
        }

        List<Handler> _handlers = new ArrayList<Handler>();

        _handlers.add(_ctx);

        HandlerList _contexts = new HandlerList();
        _contexts.setHandlers(_handlers.toArray(new Handler[0]));

        RequestLogHandler _log = new RequestLogHandler();
        _log.setRequestLog(createRequestLog());

        HandlerCollection _result = new HandlerCollection();
        _result.setHandlers(new Handler[] {_contexts, _log});

        return _result;
    }

    private RequestLog createRequestLog()
    {
        NCSARequestLog _log = new NCSARequestLog();

        File _logPath = new File(LOG_PATH);
        _logPath.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        _log.setFilename(_logPath.getPath());
        _log.setRetainDays(90);
        _log.setExtended(false);
        _log.setAppend(true);
        _log.setLogTimeZone("GMT");
        _log.setLogLatency(true);
        return _log;
    }  

    private boolean isRunningInShadedJar()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName(CLASS_ONLY_AVAILABLE_IN_IDE);
            return false;
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException anExc)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private URL getResource(String aResource)
    {
        return Thread.currentThread().
            getContextClassLoader().getResource(aResource); 
    }

    private String getShadedWarUrl()
    {
     String _urlStr = getResource(WEB_XML).toString();
        // Strip off "WEB-INF/web.xml"
        return _urlStr.substring(0, _urlStr.length() - 15);
    }
}
```

and this is the exception

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Apr 29 10:02:30 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/persistence-config.xml]
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/persistence-config.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1435)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at com.binov.web.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:71)
    at com.binov.web.Main.start(Main.java:19)
    at com.binov.web.Main.main(Main.java:7)
WARN : org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4671e53b{/,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8024-webapp-_-any-/webapp/,STARTING}{jar:file:/home/binov4/workspaceJEE/ProjectFranchiseJetty/target/franchise-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/META-INF/webapp/}
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/persistence-config.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1435)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at com.binov.web.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:71)
    at com.binov.web.Main.start(Main.java:19)
    at com.binov.web.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

First embedd jetty in your project and configure Spring's `DispatcherServlet`.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;

public class App {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

        int port = 8080;

        Server server = new Server(port);
        ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        handler.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(handler);
        handler.addServlet(org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.class, "/");
        server.start();
        server.join();

    }
}
```

And then create a runnable jar using the assembly plugin

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and finally execute `mvn clean compile assembly:single`

Comment: your answer is good and make an executable jar but when I run it show an exception.

I am going to add the WebServer Class

Comment: Please check my question again.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: please check th question again a have added the exception

Comment: Looks like the assembly plugin is not bundling up the spring's xsd. If you are using spring, you can user [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) instead of jetty. [Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) is a simple tutorial on how to get started.

Comment: but it woks in eclipse. I can start the web Application from Main.java

Comment: I works in eclipse because all the required jars and xsd are in the classpath. I'm sure that Spring boot is best for your requirement.